# For a point charge in the presence of a grounded conducting sphere, having trouble verifying the formulas for image charge and position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, method-of-images

Jackson, 3rd ed., section 2.2 states the formulas for the image charge and position, dependent on an equality of the magnitudes of two vectors:
$$
|\bar{u}-k\bar{u}'|=|\bar{u}'-k\bar{u}|
$$
Where $ |\bar{u}|=|\bar{u}'|=1 $, $k<1$. My question is how you prove this equality.

There are two unknowns in this method of images problem, the image's charge $q'$ and radius $y'$, where by symmetry we know the image charge is coaxial with the center of the sphere and the location of the proximal charge.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of the difference of the two vectors can be written in terms of the angle between $\bar{u}_1$ and $\bar{u}_2$, using the [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):
$$
|\bar{u}_1-k\bar{u}_2|=(1+k^2-2k\cos{\theta})^{1/2} = |k\bar{u}_1-\bar{u}_2|
$$
So, it matters that $|\bar{u}_1|$=$|\bar{u}_2|$, but not what $k$ is.